# Border colours - Chrome bug, or am I blind?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This image should illustrate the problem quite well: ([Fullsize](http://adamhaskell.net/img/chromebug.png))

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

As you can see, there appears to be a bug with how Chrome handles border colours when there's a border radius involved. There's a very definite cutoff, roughly when the aspect ratio of the box is 2:1 or wider.

You can imagine this makes my tab system look extremely bad in Chrome...

Is there any way to fix this behaviour?

[Live demo of the problem](https://adamhaskell.net/img/chromebug.html)

Comment: Wow. It seems all about div height to border radius ratio. Just set .box2 height to 118px or border-radius to 63px and you'll take well-look div border o_O

Comment: I know, right? I mean, if IE can get it right...

Comment: OK, so file a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: Last time I filed a bug report, it was three years ago and it has yet to receive a response or be addressed in any way... I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a clever workaround, maybe some extra property which only changes the output by an imperceptible amount, but fixes the border.

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 19. Nice find! (Or not so nice...looks like a legit bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't exactly solved it, but this is a bit big for a comment.

The unit doesn't matter it's the same with `em`, `cm`, ect.

```
div.box1 {
 border-radius: 64px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  /* OR 
    border-radius: 64px 64px 0px 64px;
  */
}
```

Will work (the light bit streches all the way), but adding a `border-bottom-right-radius` will muck it up again

As soon as one of the `border-bottom-XXX-radius`s gets below `62px`, it stops.

I don't know if this will help find the answer, but hopefully it will.

Comment: Helpful. Taken a little further by making the tabs tall enough to not experience the bug anymore, and hiding the excess behind a solid background color on following elements.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry to tell you, i use border-radius exclusive for 1 color. If i, personally, want that kind of border i would make an bankgroundimage of it, due to browser differences.

I don't think this is the answer you had hoped for, but you can use it as backup ;)